# NSTextView "data" binding problem

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSTextView textView bind its "data" to "content" property

textView's rich text support is turned off.

When textView's content changed, I have its "data" is nil, though its string and rtf is available.

```
- (NSData*)content ;

- (void)setContent:(NSData *)data;
{
    NSString* s = [textView string];
    NSData* rtf = [textView RTFDFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [s length])];
// data == nil
// s != nil
// rtf != nil
}
```

"data" is not nil if I enable textView's rich text support.

Why is "data" nil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTextView-DontLinkElementID_677):

> **data**
>
> An NSData instance containing the formatted text of the
>   NSTextView.
>
> The NSData contains either the RTF or RTFD representation of the
>   NSTextView contents, depending on the configuration of the NSTextView.
>
> ***This binding is only available when the NSTextView is configured to
>   allow multiple fonts.*** (emphasis added)

In other words, you **must** turn on Rich Text support to use this binding. If you just want to bind a plain string, use the `value` binding or for an attributed string use the `attributedString` binding instead of `data`.

Comment: I want simple saving data so I use NSData instead of NSAttributedString which I have to convert to / from NSData.